# The following jQuery code not working in some US client browsers, unable to find the issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

The following code is added in `document.ready` in page, when scroll down get records used to fetch data from Server side using Ajax call and bind the data. This code is working in local, but not in client machines. Unable to find what the issue is.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  //debugger;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
    GetRecords();
  }
});
```

In console I am getting following errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.idleTimeout is not a function

The code for this above error is:

```
<script>
var $countdown = $("#dialog-countdown");
var idealTimeout = (@Session.Timeout*60);
$.idleTimeout('#SessionIdleModal',
    '.session_stayin_btn', {
        idleAfter: idealTimeout -60,    //one minute before
        timeout:idealTimeout,
        pollingInterval: idealTimeout/2, //polling half of the timeout interval for optimization
        warningLength: 60,
        keepAliveURL:'@Url.Action("KeepSessionAlive", "Account",null, Request.Url.Scheme)',
serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
onTimeout: function () {
    window.location = '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account", null , Request.Url.Scheme)';
},
onIdle: function () {
    //$(this).dialog("open");
    $('#SessionIdleModal').css("width", "520px").popup("show");
},
redirecttologout: function () {
    $('#SessionIdleModal').hide();

    window.location = '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account", null , Request.Url.Scheme)';

    // jQuery methods go here...

},
onCountdown: function (counter) {
    $countdown.html(counter); // update the counter
    $('#ss_count').text(counter);
}
    });

</script>
```

And in console getting one more error as

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined

```
$.fn.popup.defaults.escape = false;
```

Comment: First thing you do is fix the console error, looks like the popup function hasn't been defined properly. Are you missing some Javascript?

Comment: $.fn.popup seems undefined. What is it supposed to be, a reference to a jQuery popup? Is there some popup blocker activated in the client's browser? That could explain why this popup variable is undefined.

Comment: What is probably happening is that one or more of your jQuery libraries are not loaded - could be they do not exist on these servers for some reason, or if you load them from a remote site, could be they are blocked. Check "Network" tab on dev tools to see if any js file / bundle is blocked.